# Can I declare and use a static-non-template member of a template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, static, stdmap

let's say I have:

```
namespace name{
    template< typename T >
    class Example
    {
    .... 
    };
}
```

I want to have a single instance of a map that I'll use across all the classes that inherit from `Example`. The first thing that came into my mind was having a `static` member of `Example` but it will force me to have a unique member for each class that will use it - and I don't want that due to memory usage restrictions (Am I wrong here?).

Declaring it in the `namespace` will also create an instance for each compilation unit.

What can I do to overcome this?

BTW my initial solution was to [use a const extern map][1] but I can't understand the error I'm getting there.

**EDIT:**

I've followed @SamVarshavchik answer, and now I'm getting the same error as in the previous question.

```
namespace name{

    struct Example_base {
    protected:
           static std::map<std::string, int> the_same_map;
    };

    template< typename T >
    class Example : public Example_base
    {
    .... 
    };
}
```

Results

> R_X86_64_PC32 relocation at offset 0xd3 against symbol `name::Example_base::map' can not be used; recompile with -fPIC

For each usage in every compilation unit
[1]: [R_X86_64_PC32 relocation when using a const extern map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74812120/r-x86-64-pc32-relocation-when-using-a-const-extern-map)

**Note that I've multiple instances of the classes that implement `Example` with the same template and that I can't use this flag**

Comment: Since every template class instantiation is a separate class, you cannot do that at class level, unless you're defining a common base class for your template, and put the static member there.

Comment: dont confuse class templates with classes. `Example` is a template. You cannot inherit from it.

Comment: please do not edit the question to ask for something else after you got answers. We now have a question asking abuot some error and an accepted answer that does not even mention that error. Thats odd. I suggest to revert the edit and if needed open a new question (or perhaps clarify the old one). Btw you never need to add "Edit" to a an edit. The edit history is available here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74824495/revisions for those who want to see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calls for inheritance.

```
namespace name{

    struct Example_base {
    protected:
           static std::map<std::string, int> the_same_map;
    };

    template< typename T >
    class Example : public Example_base
    {
    .... 
    };
}
```

Now, all subclasses of any instance of the `Example` template share `the_same_map`.

Comment: Note that it does not matter if inheritance or composition is used just that the static map has to be part of non-template sub-object of template class.

Comment: Thank you, I should've said it - but creating a whole new class for this single map seems too much for me.

Did you have a look at my other post?

Comment: @RedYoeal why "too much" ? If you want a static member of a class you need a class. Its not like this is adding arbitrary overhead, but just the bare minimum

Comment: You do realize that "creating a whole new class for this single map" translates to absolutely nothing at all, whatsoever, at runtime, as compared to implementing logically-equivalent functionality in any other way?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It doesn't have to be a static member of a class, I just want a variable that I'll be able to use across all of the relevant classes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do, but I don't like it in terms of design. My favorite solution is the one I referred too and it seems to be the good practice one, but it doesn't work.

Anyway - thank you again

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've tried your proposal and I get the original error from the other thread

Comment: This is a different issue that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with C++ but rather with your compiler and linker. You are apparently building a shared library but using the wrong compilation flags. You can ask a new question about that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not building a shared library, and this error appears only in specific use cases - the one you suggested and the one in the other post. If I use, for example, `inline` instead - nothing wrong besides the memory increase.

Comment: That still is not a C++ issue, but something specific to the compiler/linker configuration. And the error message tell you what the fix is: "recompile with -fPIC".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Noticed. I can't use it.